# Get the values from a column with string delimeter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I just want to know how can i get the values using select from a column with string delimeter.

Ex:
column value is:

```
    ';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple'
```

How can i get these values and save in a table like this?

```
    code   description
    10     Banana
    101    Apple
```

can't seem to get it using substring, charindex combo. Should i use function instead?
Basically, this column has a potential to store 100+ values (code/desc).

Comment: Is the data stored like this? Or is this for import from a text file?

Comment: Is this SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: Yes, the data are stored in a column as the given sample value within SQL Server table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using XML Nodes method (**[SQL-FIDDEL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15033)**)

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(500)= ';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple'

--REMOVE LEADING ROW DELIMETER `;#`
SELECT @S = SUBSTRING(@S,3, LEN(@S))


DECLARE @X XML 
SELECT @X  = '<myxml><nodes><n1>' + 
REPLACE(REPLACE (@S,';#','</n2></nodes><nodes><n1>'),';~','</n1><n2>') + 
'</n2></nodes></myxml>'


SELECT C.value('n1[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS code,
       C.value('n2[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS description
FROM @X.nodes('/myxml/nodes') Cols (C)


| CODE | DESCRIPTION |
----------------------
|   10 |      Banana |
|  101 |       Apple |
```

Comment: good one... this is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot Kaf! :)

Comment: hi Kaf, not sure if it's ok to post another question... but there is a scenario where i only need to return the description ONLY in one row delimited with a comma ','. Is this possible? TIA :)

Comment: I think you can do it using a UDF. Pass your string column to the function and return the filtered csv list of descriptions. You can use built in string functions such as  `Charindex`,`Substring` and `left/right` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the above (instead of  ',' use ';'):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
GO



select * from dbo.fnSplit('1,22,333,444,,5555,666', ',')

Results

Item

1
22
333
444
5555
666
```

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. If the link dies the answer becomes useless. Please summarise the essential parts of the page in the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or simple  substring by ';'

```
select 
   substr( column, INSTR(column, ';', 1, 1)+1, 
   (INSTR(column, ';', 1, 2 ) - INSTR(column, 1, 1 ))
   ) col_a,
   substr( column, INSTR(column, ';', 1, 2)+1, 
   (INSTR(column, ';', 1, 3 ) - INSTR(column, ';', 1, 2 ))
   ) col_b
from dual
```

Working example:

```
select 
   substr( ';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple', INSTR(';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple', ';', 1, 1)+1, 
    (INSTR(';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple', ';', 1, 2 ) - INSTR(';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple', ';', 1, 1 ))
   ) col_a,
   substr( ';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple', INSTR(';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple', ';', 1, 2)+1, 
   (INSTR(';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple', ';', 1, 3 ) - INSTR(';#10;~Banana;#101;~Apple', ';', 1, 2 ))
   ) col_b
from dual
```